Pixel 8 Pro carrier locked. Looking for a solution
I have a Pixel 8 Pro that the carrier (Spectrum) and Google both say is unlocked. The phone is definitely not unlocked. OEM unlocking is greyed out and says, "unavailable on carrier-locked devices."
One of the rude managers I talked to at Spectrum told me that spectrum doesn't lock devices. I talked to several rude people at Spectrum that all said that they did not see any lock on the device.
(Did I mention that they were all extremely rude. And I have been an internet customer with them for years.)
I chatted with Google for over an hour and they said the device appears to be unlocked and that they didn't find any problems with the phone. They said that the issue is most likely on the carriers end.
I tried with a physical sim from Cricket but it is an older sim so not sure if it would work correctly even if everything was running optimally.
With the physical sim I get the message, "Sim card isn't supported. Ask Spectrum Mobile if the device can be unlocked"
I tried two esims from different carriers and I get the message, "Can't connect to network Your device is locked. Contact your carrier to see if the device can be unlocked.
I told the people at Spectrum what the message said, and they act like I'm crazy, "The device is not locked." I felt like I was in the twilight zone.
I hope someone out there has a solution.

You should mention how was the phone obtained: direct from Google, direct from Spectrum, other third-party seller?

Sorry, this looks like an issue that can only be solved by the carrier, not something that an end-user community can help. Go to their customer service in person and show the message directly, or follow this official support from Spectrum: How to Unlock Your Spectrum Mobile Device
